Call another view from one view in ASP.NET MVC
In my main ASP.NET MVC project (Proj1) form's menu (Shared\_Menu.cshtml), I've added a new menu item to open up a view from another project (proj2) that has been added to the solution.
How do I call the proj2's view when the menu item in proj1 is clicked?

the only way to do so , is by doing an ajax request that returns the view then imbed it
iside of the html , if Proj1 & proj2 and different projects then they shoiuld not be referencing each other

@marc_s - Why are you keep messing up my post by editing it unnecessarily?  Does it make sense to you to cross out Proj1 and add Proj1 as correction?

Please help me understand...  How does it make clearer and more approachable if you replace my project name Proj1 with yours Proj1   and  Proj2 with yours Proj2?  Aren't they the same?  I've noticed the similar behavior on my other questions.
